# MySQL PHP Insert Update on duplicate key with varchar value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is my code that works OK:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO a (b1, b2, b3, b4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b3 = b3 + 1;");
$arr = explode(',', $query); 
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3]);
$stmt->execute();             
$stmt->close();
```

I need to update incrementally b3 (works fine, it is int value) and additionally insert a new value to b4 (it is varchar). This does not work:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO a (b1, b2, b3, b4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b3 = b3 + 1, b4 = VALUES(b4);");
```

My key is b1 and b2

Comment: define "does not work"

Comment: it is values(), not value()

Comment: no result - increment and new value is not changed (both are not updated)

Comment: I had mistake in the question - I have values()

Comment: Okay, it should work. If it doesn't, you are supposed to provide an MCVE as a proof.

Comment: Thank you, I had a mistake in the table structure. Thanks to your information that the code is OK, I searched in another places for the solution